# Dataflow batch job not scaling

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Dataflow job (Job ID: 2020-08-18_07_55_15-14428306650890914471) is not scaling past 1 worker, despite Dataflow setting the target workers to 1000.

The job is configured to query the Google Patents BigQuery dataset, tokenize the text using a ParDo custom function and the transformers (huggingface) library, serialize the result, and write everything to a giant parquet file.

I had assumed (after running the job yesterday, which mapped a function instead of using a beam.DoFn class) that the issue was some non-parallelizing object eliminating scaling; hence, refactoring the tokenization process as a class.

Here's the script, which is run from the command line with the following command:

```
python bq_to_parquet_pipeline_w_class.py --extra_package transformers-3.0.2.tar.gz
```

The script:

```
    import os
    import re
    import argparse
    
    import google.auth
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.options import pipeline_options
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
    from apache_beam.runners import DataflowRunner
    
    
    from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
    import pyarrow as pa
    import pickle
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer
    
    
    print('Defining TokDoFn')
    class TokDoFn(beam.DoFn):
        def __init__(self, tok_version, block_size=200):
            self.tok = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tok_version)
            self.block_size = block_size
    
        def process(self, x):
            txt = x['abs_text'] + ' ' + x['desc_text'] + ' ' + x['claims_text']
            enc = self.tok.encode(txt)
    
            for idx, token in enumerate(enc):
                chunk = enc[idx:idx + self.block_size]
                serialized = pickle.dumps(chunk)
                yield serialized
    
    
    def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
        query_big = '''
        with data as (
          SELECT 
            (select text from unnest(abstract_localized) limit 1) abs_text,
            (select text from unnest(description_localized) limit 1) desc_text,
            (select text from unnest(claims_localized) limit 1) claims_text,
            publication_date,
            filing_date,
            grant_date,
            application_kind,
            ipc
          FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` 
        )
    
        select *
        FROM data
        WHERE
          abs_text is not null 
          AND desc_text is not null
          AND claims_text is not null
          AND ipc is not null
        '''
    
        query_sample = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM `client_name.patent_data.patent_samples`
        LIMIT 2;
        '''
    
        print('Start Run()')
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    
        '''
        Configure Options
        '''
        # Setting up the Apache Beam pipeline options.
        # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
        # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
        options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
        options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    
        # Sets the project to the default project in your current Google Cloud environment.
        _, options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = google.auth.default()
    
        # Sets the Google Cloud Region in which Cloud Dataflow runs.
        options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).region = 'us-central1'
    
    
        # IMPORTANT! Adjust the following to choose a Cloud Storage location.
        dataflow_gcs_location = 'gs://client_name/dataset_cleaned_pq_classTok'
        # Dataflow Staging Location. This location is used to stage the Dataflow Pipeline and SDK binary.
        options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = f'{dataflow_gcs_location}/staging'
    
        # Dataflow Temp Location. This location is used to store temporary files or intermediate results before finally outputting to the sink.
        options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = f'{dataflow_gcs_location}/temp'
    
        # The directory to store the output files of the job.
        output_gcs_location = f'{dataflow_gcs_location}/output'
    
        print('Options configured per GCP Notebook Examples')
        print('Configuring BQ Table Schema for Beam')
    
    
        #Write Schema (to PQ):
        schema = pa.schema([
            ('block', pa.binary())
        ])
    
        print('Starting pipeline...')
        with beam.Pipeline(runner=DataflowRunner(), options=options) as p:
            res = (p
                   | 'QueryTable' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query_big, use_standard_sql=True))
                   | beam.ParDo(TokDoFn(tok_version='gpt2', block_size=200))
                   | beam.Map(lambda x: {'block': x})
                   | beam.io.WriteToParquet(os.path.join(output_gcs_location, f'pq_out'),
                                            schema,
                                            record_batch_size=1000)
                   )
            print('Pipeline built. Running...')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import logging
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logging.getLogger("transformers.tokenization_utils_base").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        run()
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have enough quotas to launch 1000 machines.

Comment: Can I ask where you are seeing that?

Comment: Note that the target workers are set to 1000, while the number of actual workers stays at 1. I'm not being notified that I'm attempting to exceed any quota, so I'm not quite sure where to look re: increasing my quotas.

Comment: Please check /iam-admin/quotas/details for Compute Engine CPUs to see if you have enough quotas to launch 1000 workers. The number of target workers indicates how many machines Dataflow wants and is not constrained by your quota.

Comment: @PeterKim my us-central-1 quota for Compute Engine API CPUs is 24, and the page says I'm currently using 1. Could it be that since Dataflow is trying to scale to 1000 straight away, it's failing to notice that it could just scale to 24 and stop there? Seems like someone would have caught that bug already.

Comment: Note that, during the BigQuery read/export step, target workers was set to 200ish. Explicitly, from start to present, the target workers level was 1, then 203, now 1000. Is it not possible to say to Dataflow (via the Python SDK, if possible) "use the max of my available quote and notify my when it is reached?"

Comment: I don't think Dataflow checks your quota before requesting more workers, but I'm not 100% sure on this. Does your job scale when you set max number of workers to something smaller than 24? Since you know the quota, you can add `--max_num_workers=24`.

Answer (score 4):

**The solution is twofold:**

The following quotas were being exceeded when I ran my job, all under 'Compute Engine API' (view your quotas here: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas):

- CPUs (I requested an increase to 50)
- Persistent Disk Standard (GB) (I requested an increase to 12,500)
- In_Use_IP_Address (I requested an increase to 50)

**Note:** If you read the console output while your job is running, any exceeded quotas should print out as an INFO line.

Following Peter Kim's advice above, I passed the flag --max_num_workers as part of my command:

```
python bq_to_parquet_pipeline_w_class.py --extra_package transformers-3.0.2.tar.gz --max_num_workers 22
```

And I started scaling!

All in all, it would be nice if there was a way to prompt users via the Dataflow console when a quota is being reached, and provide an easy means to request an increase to that (and recommended complementary) quotas, along with suggestions for what the increased amount to be requested should be.